# Get specific text from a div and make into a link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, text, hyperlink

I'm not sure if this is possible, I've been trying with jQuery but haven't got far.

I want to get the text from inside a div and turn them into links.

The problem is that I want the 3 names to become separate links eg href="/staff/john" , href="/staff/sarah" and href="/staff/mike"

any help would be much appreciated.

```html
<div id="container">
john, sarah, mike
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this - no jQuery needed

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.innerHTML = container.textContent.split(",")
  .map(name => `<a href="/staff/${name.trim().toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ","-")}">${name.trim()}</a>`)
  .join(", ")
```

```html
<div id="container">
John Doe, Sarah Doe, Mike Hunt
</div>
```

but if you want jQuery you can do

```js
$("#container").html(function() {
  return $(this).text().split(",")
    .map(name => `<a href="/staff/${name.trim().toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ","-")}">${name.trim()}</a>`)
    .join(", ")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  John Doe, Sarah Doe, Mike Hunt
</div>
```

Comment: You're amazing, thank you that worked a charm. one more problem is there a way to add a "-" any time there is a space between the names where i'm actually using this there is a first and last name